# How could I check cpu_online_mask work properly

Tags: c, linux, embedded-linux

Currently I tried to boot multi-core Linux with riscv emulator (without OpenSBI), but there is a problem in secondary cpus boot.

```bash
[    0.016639] smp: Bringing up secondary CPUs ...
[    1.037847] CPU1: failed to come online
```

In [smpboot.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/riscv/kernel/smpboot.c), I think there is a problem with `cpu_online(cpu)`

```c
int __cpu_up(unsigned int cpu, struct task_struct *tidle)
{
    int ret = 0;
    tidle->thread_info.cpu = cpu;

    ret = start_secondary_cpu(cpu, tidle);
    if (!ret) {
        wait_for_completion_timeout(&cpu_running,
                        msecs_to_jiffies(1000));

        if (!cpu_online(cpu)) {
            pr_crit("CPU%u: failed to come online\n", cpu);
            ret = -EIO;
        }
    } else {
        pr_crit("CPU%u: failed to start\n", cpu);
    }

    return ret;
}
```

[cpumask.h](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/cpumask.h#L1080)

```c
static inline bool cpu_online(unsigned int cpu)
{
    return cpumask_test_cpu(cpu, cpu_online_mask);
}
```

I wonder to know how `cpu_online_mask` be set.

Or other reasons that will cause `CPU1: failed to come online` issue.

I tried to insert `pr_crit` in kernel code, but no help.